# cosmosDB Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at trimSlashes

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Im facing an issue where I try to create an item to cosmosDB but whenever I try to save an item it complains about trimSlashes function.

Language: Nodejs 10.x.x
Npm moduel: "@azure/cosmos": "^3.7.4",

The Error:

```
{ TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at trimSlashes (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\dist\index.js:324:23)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\dist\index.js:7002:40
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:110:16)
    at httpRequest (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\dist\index.js:6979:22)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\dist\index.js:6375:24
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\@azure\cosmos\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:75
  headers:
   { 'x-ms-throttle-retry-count': 0,
     'x-ms-throttle-retry-wait-time-ms': 0 } }
```

The Input:

```
{ id: '1',
  subEntries: 'a',
  errorName: 'b',
  errorMessage: 'c',
  errorCode: 'd',
  errorStack: 'e' }

 { id: '1'}
```

The code:

```
async function saveToCosmosDB(error) {
    const client = new CosmosClient({ cosmosDBEndpoint, cosmosDBKey });
    const database = client.database(cosmosDBDatabase);
    let container = database.container(cosmosDBContainer);
    const res = await container.items.create(error);
    return res
}
```

Now I have tried with different inputs also where I only pass the ID in the input all of them is failing for some reason. Tried with defining the partition key as in above example, also tried without it, it seems all of them end up the same error, and at this moment im clueless what could cause it.
Also checked tutorials and official documentations.

eg:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application
eg:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-samples

Any help appreciated to move forward with this.

***Edit***

I was digging into the node_module library a bit and it seems this error happens when the package tries to connect to the database, which is really weird since the cosmos DB im working with is public, and also no restrictions on azure function from NSG. Will post an update/solution once found one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short the error was a syntax/naming error:
Re naming the passed variables when i create the new CosmosClient will solve the issue. From my opinion its pretty much dumb that SDK dont throw meaningfull error. Also there are other issues with the SDK i ran into, which connects to partitionKeyDefinition issues. But this thread is considered as solved from my side.

```
async function saveToCosmosDB(error) {
    const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, key});
    const database = client.database(cosmosDBDatabase);
    let container = database.container(cosmosDBContainer);
    const res = await container.items.create(error);
    return res
}
```